# line break issue caused file corruption

Tags: windows, perl, file-io, line-breaks

I downloaded one zip file from the server using getstore() function in the perl script and  unzipped the filed using Unzip method. Now if I try to access that file, I see below error.

> ERROR:XXX file corrupted, CR found. Likely cause is file line endings
>   translated from Unix to CR+LF format

No such error was not seen when I manually download the file by clicking hyper-link and unzip it using windows extraction method. Could anybody please explain why it might be happening? Is there anyway we can access the corrupted file using some tool/application?

Comment: More detail is needed as to exactly what you're doing.

Comment: In automation, we are trying to download multiple coverage files from a server using perl script. particularly using getstore() function(exposed through LWP::simple API) by passing url and filename.

now, when I'm feeding that downloaded file to some application. Then application is reporting above error.

If I download file manually, and feed it to the application then we don't see above error.

Comment: Please see [ask] for some detail on what makes a good (and more importantly, answerable) question.

Comment: just updated my comment if you are able to understand it.

Comment: Ideally, you'll be editing things that are relevant to your question actually into your question. However that's still not sufficient information - typically sample code is a good start, or otherwise enough to reproduce the error.

Comment: Is your script running on a *nix system or Windows?

Comment: script is running on windows. And File System is fat32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LWP::Simple's `getstore` writes to disk exactly what was received.

It's your browser that's "corrupting" the file. If you wish to perform the same "corruption" as your web browser, i.e. if you wish to convert DOS line endings to unix line endings, you can use the command line utility `dos2unix`.

Or you could modify your Perl script to get without storing, convert the line endings, and store the converted result.

Comment: Correct, agreed with you. getstore doesn't change the file. 

Specifically, I was downloading the zip file using getstore() method. And unzipping the file using unzip method

use IO::Uncompress::Unzip qw(unzip $UnzipError);
unzip $covZip => $covFile or die "unzip failed: $UnzipError\n"; //root cause

We are getting two different files if I unzip the file using the above method or unzip file using windows extraction method.

dos2unix utility fixed the issue.